# App not presenting modal view controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

I have a view controller that I want to present from my root view controller when the view is load.

I have set the presenting view controller as the delegate for the presented view.

I have a `UIBarbutton` that when I tap, the view is presented with no problem using a method that does the exact same thing as the `viewDidLoad`, in the `viewDidLoad` method I try to present the view:

```
modalViewController.delegate = self;
modalViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
[self presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:YES];
```

it's not working.

Is it a problem to try to present the view in the `viewDidLoad` method?

The whole viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"              "
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                                 target:self
                                                                 action:@selector(changePlayersNames)];//Check how to highlight the button
//Label for UIBarButton text
UILabel *barButtonLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 5, 70, 30)];
barButtonLabel.text = @"Players";
[barButtonLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ChalkboardSE-Bold" size:15.0]];
barButtonLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
barButtonLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
barButtonLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

//Set UINavigation item
UINavigationItem *item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""];
item.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton;
item.hidesBackButton = YES;
[navigationBar pushNavigationItem:item animated:YES];

//Label for the navigation title
UILabel *barTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 30)];
barTitleLabel.center = navigationBar.center;
barTitleLabel.text = @"Tic-Tac-Toe";
[barTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ChalkboardSE-Bold" size:20.0]];
barTitleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
barTitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
barTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[self.view addSubview:navigationBar];
[self.view addSubview:barTitleLabel];
[self.view addSubview:barButtonLabel];

self.player1 = [[ORDPlayer alloc] init];
self.player2 = [[ORDPlayer alloc] init];

[self setNamesLabels:@"Player 1" :@"Player 2"];


//TapRecognizer
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapRecognized:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
singleTap.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

//Present modal view
self.playerChangeController = [[ORDPlayerChangeController alloc]
                               initWithNibName:@"ORDPlayerChangeController" bundle:nil];
playerChangeController.delegate = self;
playerChangeController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
[self presentModalViewController:playerChangeController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: btw, you set transition style for another vc

Comment: the viewDidLoad method should do the job ok. Do you have much else going on in viewDidLoad? If so perhaps post the whole method. Where / how are you allocating/initialising the modalViewController?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot present your view controller from `viewDidLoad`, especially not `animated`. At that point you might still be creating subviews, so the view is not even rendered yet.

Instead, you should try presenting your modal view controller in `viewDidAppear`.